# python how to sort a variable like {'a b': c, 'd e':f ....}

Tags: python, sorting

I have a variable.

`Score = {}`

After some calculation, the value of Score is :

```
{
'449 22876': 0.7491997,
'3655 6388': 0.99840045,
'2530 14648': 0.9219989,
'19957 832': 0.9806836,
'2741 23293': 0.64072967,
'22324 7525': 0.986661,
'9090 3811': 0.90206504,
'10588 5352': 0.8018138,
'18231 7515': 0.9991332,
'17807 14648': 0.9131582
.....
}
```

I want to sort it by the third value(e.g. 0.7491997).
I only want to get the top 100 high score.
How can I do?

Comment: Why does `score` have its key as the first two values separated by a space? are you sure you want that?

Comment: Ignoring *why* you'd want to do that, have a look here: [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/4644044)

Comment: Do you want a sorted dictionary with the top 100 values, or just the top 100 values in  a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to sort the dictionary by the values of the dictionary (which is what I am getting from your question) you could do it with this lambda function:

```
    sorted_dict = sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: But your answer is ascending order, not descending order
If I want to change it to descending order, how do I do?

Comment: sorted_dict = sorted(score.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)